# Diffeomorphism preserves dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry, inverse-function-theorem, diffeomorphism

I want to apply the inverse function theorem to a general mapping that is a diffeomorphism. The inverse function theorem, as stated in my textbook, requires that the dimension of the range and domain spaces be equal. I see in the post [Diffeomorphism preserves dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399929/diffeomorphism-preserves-dimension)

that this is indeed the case where the range and domain of the mapping are **open subsets** of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$. My question is, can you have a diffeomorphism between **all** of $\Bbb R^n$ and **all** of $\Bbb R^m$ where $n$ and $m$ are not equal?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: All of $\Bbb R^n$ is also an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 4):

No, since a diffeomorphism $f$ between smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$ induces
a vector space isomorphism between tangent spaces $T_p(M)$ and $T_{f(p)}(N)$ for all $p\in M$. This means the tangent spaces have the same
dimension, and so the manifolds have the same dimension.

This is also true for homeomorphisms, but the proof is harder
(see Brouwer's "invariance of domain" theorem).